# Copy and paste data from the 1st row into empty rows beneath till it reach the next row with data and repeat

Tags: vba

I have 100 rows of data in row 2 to 101 from Column A to G.
Cell A2 to E2 have been filled up and F2 to G2 are initially blank.

- I want to insert 50 empty rows in between each of these rows.
- After inserting the 50 empty rows each.  I will key in data in Column F&G (eg Cell F2 to G52).

I wish to copy and paste the data from the first row (eg A2 to E2) into the remaining 50 blank cells A3 to E52 automatically. This process will repeat for the rest of the 99 rows.

Comment: Please ask a question (programming-related if possible, not just "tell me how to do that")

Answer (score 0):

When inserting/deleting rows or columns it is considered best practise to start at the bottom for rows or the right for columns and work toward A1.

```
Sub clone_row_data()
    Dim rw As Long, lr As Long, frw As Long, lrw As Long, blnks As Long

    frw = 2    'first row
    lrw = 100  'last row
    blnks = 50 'insert this many blanks

    With ActiveSheet
        For rw = lrw To frw Step -1
            .Cells(rw, 1).Offset(1, 0).Resize(blnks, 5).EntireRow.Insert
            .Cells(rw, 1).Resize(blnks + 1, 5).FillDown
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```

By working backwards, you can keep a simple incremental count and avoid having rows/columns skipped over or repeated.

Answer (score 0):

Jeeped. It worked & thanks for your prompt response.
I have 10 rows of data in row 2 to 11 from ColA to G. Cell A2 to G11 have been filled up. This is group 1 data.  I have 25 rows of data in row 12 to 36 from ColA to L.  This is group 2 data.  I have remaining 98 groups of data (within each group, it filled up different columns). 
(a) I want to insert 1 empty row in between each group. 
(b) For Group 1, I wish to copy and paste the data from the last row of each group (eg C11 to G11) into the next blank C12 to G12 automatically. A11 is the reference date (Mar2015) and B11 is a figure.  I want A12 to contain the next period (Apr2015) and B12 to be blank. I will key in data in Col B (eg Cell B12). 
(c) For Group 2, to copy and paste data from A36 to L36 into next blank A37 to L37 automatically. A36 is the reference date (2010) and M36 is a figure. I want to A37 to contain the next period (2011) and M37 to be blank. I will key in data in Column M (eg Cell M37).
This process will repeat for the rest of the 98 groups. Within each group, it filled up different columns.